# Образ жары в художественной литературе

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, литература

1. В Сети мне встретился вопрос о правильности предложения (по смыслу и пунктуации):

***На улицах небольшого посёлка кипел жуткий зной, окуная в свои жаркие объятия пустующие улицы скромного поселения**.*

Мы видим желание автора создать интересный художественный образ, но как-то не всё у него получилось.

2. Был предложен вариант правки с пояснением: *Раз этот зной уже кипел на улицах посёлка, так он давно уж окунул в свои жаркие объятия эти улицы. Нужно описать процесс, отчего пустуют улицы.
   Можно написать как-то так, исправляя эту временнУю накладку:*

***По улицам небольшого посёлка растекался жуткий зной**, окуная в свои жаркие объятия пустующие улицы скромного поселения.*

3. Но предложение, по моему мнению, не стало намного лучше. А что бы предложили вы, чтобы оно выглядело как цитата их художественного произведения, то есть интересно и правильно. Желательно сохранить основной образ, а можно описать ситуацию по-своему.

Помогите, пожалуйста, писатели, художники и просто любители литературы! Здесь требуется ваш тонкий художественный вкус.

Спасибо.

**20.04.2022 год**

Итак, **конкурс заканчивается**, и я благодарю всех его участников!
Пора подвести итоги.

Премия (увы, единственная!) присуждается  **Александру Стрельцу за стихотворный текст,** написанный Онегинской строфой.

Оригинальный выбор формы, легкий «пушкинский» стих, интересные нестандартные образы, неожиданные словосочетания и переходы от речи художественной к речи обыденной – все это кажется мне истинной поэзией,  достойной самой высокой оценки.

Жаль, что вторая премия не предусмотрена правилами, но ее, несомненно, заслуживает другой наш участник – **Nektoid,** поэтому я просто **принимаю его ответ.** Я благодарю его за активное участие в конкурсе, за безупречный в художественном отношении вариант ответа, который также достоин оценки **не менее высокой.**

Всем другим конкурсантам я могу предложить только **самую искреннюю благодарность.** Надеюсь, что мы попробовали свои силы в творчестве, стали умнее и кое-чему научились, общаясь друг с другом.

До новых конкурсов!

Comment: Не надо ли этот вопрос в конкурсные отправить?

Comment: Можно, конечно,  отправить, но не сразу, а через два дня.

Comment: Я тоже пытаюсь поучаствовать... Подождёте менЮ? Только, может быть, даже не сегодня.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец
Подождем вас... Вот что удивительно, так это то, то вы читаете мои мысли. Не далее как сегодня я написала вам письмо на почту по поводу конкурса, но отправить его не удалось (Сеть утром не работала). Но письмо, видно, все-таки "дошло", так как вы на него отвечаете. Мистика! Конечно, мы с удовольствием почитаем вас, ну и покритикуем немного, не без этого. :) Здесь каждому участнику "доставалось", даже внеконкурсному (видели, наверное). Впрочем, кажется, не всем, про одного мы забыли...

Comment: Нет, письмо так и не пришло. Я вчера хотел отправить ответ, но так засиделся и расфантазировался, что аж до пяти утра не мог уснуть. Так много мыслей, что теперь не знаю, когда они устаканятся и созреет «шедевр» 

Comment: Ну да, не дошло, потому что я передумала и не стала его отправлять, вот  и говорю – мистика.  А в стихах можно? Как у Рождественского, а? Ну а первый вариант в прозе. Тогда все мысли можно разместить. :)

Comment: Если еще и в стихах (но только как у Стрельца), то вообще могу надолго закопаться...

Comment: Вы их присылайте в порядке очередности, не все сразу. У вас же еще целых пять дней!

Comment: Давно у нас не *кипели* и не "жаре́лись" такие страсти! Спасибо, Sharon, — с плюсом.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова А я вот уже несколько дней вспонимаю о ваших талантах и хотел написать просто: *Ау-у, Римма!..* Интересно, почему ударение стоит так:  *не "жарéлись".*

Comment: Это вот так происходило (приблизительно). Летом шли с любопытной девочкой, автором нескольких детских вопросов (года три или четыре назад), на речку. Девочка сняла кофточку. *— Тебе не холодно? — Нет, тепло. Я даже вся обжаре́лась. — Может, обжа́рилась? — Нет, жара́ ведь, значит, обжаре́лась. И обпотелась...* Я не стала ее переубеждать. Но словечки запомнились.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Здóрово! Да, девочка молодчинка, а язык – велик и могуч.

Comment: Sharon, спасибо большое за оценку, интересный опыт, поиск, сомнения... До новых встреч на просторах русского языка!

Comment: Спасибо за ваше участие. Мне сразу ваш стих очень понравился,  мгновенное впечатление, узнавание... Мне кажется, что оно самое верное. И до новых встреч...

Comment: Извините, но мне кажется, что Ваше изменение шапки не совсем удачно: *Художественная правка предложения "Образ жары в художественной литературе"*. Разве у нас было **такое** предложение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ответ для конкурса:** *Нонеча жарынь, куры прям на дворе чуть не запекаются! Раскочегарилось к лету солнышко-то, ровно кизяк в печи.*

**На улицах небольшого посёлка кипел жуткий зной, окуная в свои жаркие объятия пустующие улицы скромного поселения.**

Ошибки:

1. Двоящийся образ: зной кипел и зной обнимал. К тому же "окунул в объятия" мне кажется стилистически неверным. Можно окунутьСЯ в объятия, можно заключить в объятия.
2. Излишнее количество согласованных определений: *небольшого, жуткий, жаркие,
   пустующие, скромного*.
3. "Скромное поселение" — слишком топорный контекстный синоним к "небольшому посёлку".
4. "Улицах" и "улицы": слишком рядом.

**Исправляем, сокращаем, избавляемся от лишних слоёв образов:**

**Вариант 1:** *По улицам небольшого посёлка кипятком струился зной — и они пустовали.*

Хорошо? Лучше, но не очень, потому что улицы не пустуют: на них кипяток зноя. Поэтому исправим чуть ещё:

**Вариант 2:** *По улицам небольшого посёлка кипятком струился зной — и на них не было ни души.*

Ещё лучше, но я бы переставил местами причину и следствие:

**Вариант 3:** *На улицах небольшого посёлка не было ни души: по ним кипятком струился зной.*

Вот так годится. Но лично мне не хватает в таком образе всеохватной жары. Я бы изменил и усилил бы ощущение так:

**Вариант 4:** *На улицах небольшого посёлка не было ни души, только подрагивало марево зная: казалось, это сама реальность лагает от перегрева.*

(Естественно, четвёртый вариант уместен только в том случае, если позволяет сеттинг произведения. Нельзя образ с лагом использовать в книге про времена царя Иоанна Грозного или в книге про мир меча и магии, если только главный герой не попаданец, знающий, что такое компьютер.)

Comment: Спасибо! Критика мне, конечно же, нравится, только термин "двоящийся образ" не очень понятен. А вот варианты правки – скорее нет.  Слово "кипяток" совсем не художественное, глагол "кипеть" в этом плане лучше. Теперь о варианте 4.  Мне тоже пришлось поработать со словарем, хотя я вроде бы не "попаданец", но это только на пользу.  Марево зноя – это дрожащая дымка или что это? "Лагает" меня, конечно, напрягает – это все-таки компьютерный термин. Я бы написала примерно так: На улицах небольшого посёлка  – ни души, только  марево зноя: казалось, сама реальность ( дрожит, мерцает…)  от перегрева.

Comment: @Sharon Можно и так, конечно. Вариантов много. Можно "кипящий", но тогда лучше убрать "небольшого", чтобы не было подряд двух определений в препозиции: "По улицам посёлка струился кипящий зной — и на них не было ни души". // Что касается "двоящегося образа" -- есть такой приём, как антанаклазис, использование сло́ва в двух смыслах: "Я разбил сад и сердце". Зной кипел, окуная (лучше: заключая) в объятия... Чуете двоение? Зной кипел -- нормальный образ. Зной заключал в объятия -- нормальный образ. А вот "склеивание" в одну конструкцию выглядит как Франкенштейн.

Comment: @Sharon "от перегрева" хорошо звучит с "лагает", но в вашем случае уже не так уместно, по канцелярски. Далее. У вас настоящее время, и вдруг: "казалось". Не годится. "На улицах небольшого посёлка – ни души, только марево зноя: кажется, что сама реальность оплывает от жара".

Comment: Ну да, по ходу – " кажется". ( Я действую в рамках информативного стиля (пиши, сокращай", он действительно помогает убирать лишние слова.) А сколько же нового узнаешь при общении с вами!  Мне в принципе непонятен образ "заключать улицы в объятия", зной скорее заполняет собою улицы. А ваш окончательный вариант в качестве образца, может быть, напишете?

Comment: @Sharon *На улицах посёлка не было ни души, лишь колыхалось жаркое марево: казалось, будто сама реальность оплывает от зноя"*.

Comment: Спасибо, вариант принят! Это к тому, что мне тут намекают на конкурс, если будут еще ответы.

Comment: @Sharon можно ещё улучшить, раз уж на конкурс, я подумаю как. Безликий глагол 'было' лучше заменить, а также избавиться от 'тавтологии окончаний' ("колыхаЛОСЬ" — "казаЛОСЬ").

Comment: Конечно, можно еще править! А для конкурса нужна еще хотя бы пара ответов, н о я надеюсь, что наши участники проявят активность... Только вы свой вариант пока держите в секрете:)

Comment: @Sharon кстати, обратите внимание, что в моём варианте уместен переход от прошедшего времени к настоящему. Это распространённый приём, когда ощущения персонажа (в данном случае рассказчика), вводимые через глагол типа "казалось", "чудилось" или глаголы восприятия, пишутся в настоящем времени. Из Нацкорпуса: "Весь дрожа от возбуждения и вцепившись в ногу Курта, я смотрел на силок, и мне казалось, что Курт пропустит нужное мгновение, щеглы снимутся и улетят".

Comment: Я думаю, что время в сравнительном обороте теряет конкретность и становится неопределенным (Present Indefinite), поэтому форма настоящего времени здесь вполне уместна.

Comment: @Sharon не только в сравнительном. С глаголами восприятия тоже так работает. "Андрей услышал какое-то шуршание, поднял глаза и увидел, что жена Антона надевает сапоги" (Пелевин); "Он осторожно лег рядом с ней и почувствовал, что она дрожит" (Распутин).

Comment: А может, и в моем варианте (в  комментарии) можно оставить "казалось (будто)". Форма прошедшего времени, к примеру,  используется в сослагательном наклонении, а уподобление – это тоже не сама реальность.

Comment: @Sharon нет, там начало предложения уже в наст. вр., поэтому не годится. Такой переход возможен при рассказе в наст. вр. о прошедшем: "Заходит бабушка и говорит, как мне (тогда) казалось, строго: "Иди-ка грядки поливать!"

Comment: Я про связочки вспомнила. Там есть два похожих на связки варианта: нонеча – к лету, на дворе –  в печи.  А как правильно?

Comment: @Sharon нет, тут связочка попроще) Куры запекаются — кизяк в печи. То есть здесь "зарифмован" образ печи, духового шкафа.

Comment: Ну ладно... А сами говорили – противопоставление.

Comment: @Sharon я говорил, помнится, "например, противопоставление". Это лишь один из варинатов внутрифрагментной арки. Я приводил и пример "Банный выдох июля" -- "протопленная атмосфера", где арка строится, как здесь, на образах одного ряда.

Comment: Ну да, я тоже думала: где тут противопоставление? Теперь понятно, связочки могут быть разного вида.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135587/discussion-on-answer-by-nektoid---).

Comment: @МаркИз это конкурсное обсуждение; мне кажется, такое начинание стоило бы поддержать как-то (тем более что сайт "Русский язык" скорее мёртв, чем жив, а тут хоть какая-то активность), а не раскидывать обсуждения по чатам, которые скоро удалятся.

Comment: @МаркИз Верните, пожалуйста, комментарии сюда.

Answer (score 4):

После стольких описаний зноя становится невыносимо жарко!  И очень сложно нащупать что-то новое, не повторить эпитеты, форму изложения... Отправляю пока что есть, а то уже совсем всё перепуталось и запал тухнет.

**На конкурс:**

*Как беспощадно бывает солнце! Адский зной на целых три недели превратил наш посёлок в кипящий котёл. Ни тень, ни жилище, ни раннее утро никому не давали передышки. Пожар неба – неотступный, изнуряющий, жестокий – решил, казалось, задушить в своих объятиях всё живое, опустевшие улочки потеряли даже своих гостей – теплолюбивых ящерок, часто греющихся на каменных мостовых в обычные солнечные дни...*

**Цитаты из Нацкорпуса:**

*Потом опять душным гнетом налегала тишина, волны выравнивались и с безоблачного неба бесшумными потоками лился палящий зной.* [И. Е. Вольнов. Повесть о днях моей жизни (1912)]

*Небо дышало зноем, накаляя неподвижный воздух, ослепительным блеском отражаясь в синеве моря.* [А. С. Новиков-Прибой. Шалый (1917)]

*Папа отправился сегодня на велосипеде на ту сторону реки Луги и чуть не сгорел ― такой испепеляющий зной, такое жгучее солнце.* [А. И. Пантелеев. Наша Маша (1966)]

*С утра раскаленное солнце начинало свою опустошительную работу, медленно плыло в белесом, выцветшем небе, излучая нестерпимый зной, а к вечеру, малиново-красное, тонуло в мутной дымке за горизонтом.* [Л. И. Брежнев. Целина (1977)]

*Нетрудно было представить себе, как он пьет и теряет рассудок, как чувствует себя ― покрывшийся липким потом и обессиленный этой жуткой жарой, этим воздухом, в котором, кажется, не осталось кислорода.* [Евгений Рубин. Пан или пропал. Жизнеописание (1999-2000)]

*Давно, упрямо и прочно стоявшая изнурительная жара, не желающая даже вечерами уступать место хотя бы относительной прохладе, накопившаяся в перегретом воздухе какой-то диковатой массой, выжелтившая кое-где листву, иссушившая почву, сделавшая сухими и колючими травы на Тепсене и прочих окрестных холмах, воду в море превратившая в теплое варево, почти не освежающее, в котором растворились без следа остатки той бодрости, что является обычно следствием морского купания, длинными волокнами и обволакивающими волнами перемещавшаяся от нечего делать по дворам, по садам, где не знали, куда им деваться, деревья с обвисшими кронами, сутулившимися стволами, душными сгустками нависавшая в доме, по всем углам, по всем закуткам, застревавшая в шторах, буквально клубящаяся под потолком, в этот день умерила свой пыл.* [В. Д. Алейников. Тадзимас (2002)]

**Критиковать** можно всех и вся. Вот это последнее огромное предложение Алейникова, где из знаков препинания одни запятые, кишит причастиями, но оно мне понравилось – эта "навязчивость" создаёт всеобъемлющий портрет жары. Хотя, например, можно немного споткнуться в ряду творительного падежа: ***с обвисшими кронами, сутулившимися стволами, душными сгустками...***

Участники конкурса уже много сказали о вариантах друг друга. Мне нравится ваш творческий потенциал.
Хотел поначалу отметить повторы у Артёма: ***словно*** и ***пытаясь***, но они исчезли, а текст изменился в лучшую сторону, преобразился. Небольшая грамматическая корректировка: в последнем предложении я бы убрал ***то*** и поставил запятую перед ***прибитый***.
Юмор Nektoid'a хорошо разбавляет тяжёлую общую атмосферу сей темы, вот только вариант короток, чтобы в полной мере прочувствовать её, да и сам стиль не способствует этому.
Всем спасибо, всем плюс: Артёму – за хорошую правку своего сочинения, Nektoid'у – больше за критику изначального предложения и активное участие во всех обсуждениях, Надежде – за внезапность появления и проявленный интерес, организатору конкурса – просто так. ☺

Comment: Спасибо за весь материал, очень интересно!  Надо долго читать всё и вдумываться.  Я, конечно, начну с оригинала, потом расскажу о впечатлении...  А стихи когда-нибудь потом, да? Можно даже после конкурса, если, конечно,  будет настроение...Почему-то очень хочется стихов.

Comment: @Sharon а чё, ещё и стихом было можно? Тогда я вне конкурса что-нибудь рожу в рифму)

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец вы правы, что у Алейникова хорошо звучит, потому что у него разновидность *эмфазы* (https://writercenter.ru/blog/useful-stuff/ekspressivnaja-rech.html)

Comment: Отличный ответ, Александр! Спасибо и за хорошие слова и советы по исправлению мне! Запятую сам раздумывал, надо поставить или нет, но вот *то* что-то не хочется убирать...

Comment: @ Nektoid  Еще как можно! Варианты в прозе и в стихах  совершенно разные. Стихам-описаниям несвойственны плавные  переходы,  там зрительные образы и чувства в большей степени фрагментарны, неожиданны. И они более понятны читателю, позволяют ему больше видеть и меньше рассуждать и оценивать. И конечно, мне очень интересно, какой вы поэт! У меня даже появляется желание продолжить конкурс, но уже для поэтов...

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Мне тоже с ***то*** больше нравится, звучит плавнее. Я чисто из грамматических сообращений подумал, что при изъятии ***если какой и попадался*** структура ломается.

Comment: Действительно! Может, после "пешехода" тогда убрать запятую?

Comment: Пиши, сокращай... Без "то" вроде бы лучше, получается симпатичный обособленный оборот (вставка), грамматика меняется. Раньше двойной союз относился к сказуемым, а без "то" самостоятельное придаточное

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Может, и можно. Только вот ее тоже не хочется убирать, там явно должна быть пауза и вставочный характер.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Точно, убирайте ***то***. Сразу еще больше добавляется монотонности, образ плетущегося, уставшего пешехода считывается лучше, этому и обилие запятых в помощь.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец
 Александр, что-то я не вижу отзывов  о вашей работе, но надеюсь они появятся – ведь вам же тоже интересно услышать мнение других конкурсантов. А можно мне написать не критику, а изложение по вашему рассказу. Ну как в школе, когда слушают текст, а потом записывают содержание своими словами –  что запомнили.  У меня вот такой "оригинальный" подход, вы не будете против?  Мне нужно ваше разрешение.

Comment: @Sharon Вот это здóрово! Конечно не против. Критику услышать хочу, я и сам не очень доволен и предположительно знаю, на чём можно заострить внимание. Может, мы все немного устали, да и другие дела тоже есть под этим, пусть не палящим, солнцем.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  Вы правы, иногда экспромтом текст получается лучше, чем когда долго над ним работаешь и просто устаешь. Тогда его лучше отложить в сторону и вернуться к теме позже. А мне легче вас "пересказать".

Comment: Беспощадное, безжалостное солнце!  Адский зной стоит в поселке уже третью неделю. С раннего утра бледно-желтый диск застывает в туманном, словно кипящем мареве. Ни тень, ни жилище, ни редкий ветерок никому не дают передышки. Жар неба – неотступный, изнуряющий, жестокий – решил, казалось, задушить в своих объятиях все живое. Исчезли даже теплолюбивые ящерки, греющиеся на каменных мостовых в обычные солнечные дни.

Answer (score 4):

Просили в стихах. Я не поэт, и даже не учусь. 
Но пусть уж здесь будет (ух, сколько сразу У!) и эта Онегинская строфа:

*Мороз? Жара? Что хуже? Впрочем,

Сейчас повестка о второй...

Июль. Посёлок даже ночью

Зажат в тисках у силы злой.

Звезда зачем-то душит зноем.

Сходить по вóду – стать героем:

Кипящий воздух строит блок

В котле из стен, камней дорог.

Жестокий гнёт стирает звуки.

Ни облачка, ни ветерка.

В ручей сужается река.

Все ждут дождя и терпят муки.

Рассказ «Жара» я напишу...

О небо! Смилуйся, прошу!*

Comment: Александр, спасибо огромное  за стихи! О своем впечатлении я пока не буду  говорить, но надеюсь, что вы и так догадались...

Comment: И вам и вам! У меня ещё вымучивались две жаркие штуки – одна "прозная", другая анапестом.

Comment: Теперь понятно, сколько усилий вы затратили :)  Как собираетесь с ними поступить – надо бы домучить и здесь опубликовать. Я после конкурса изменю название  на "Образ жары в литературе",  Чтобы читателей было больше.

Comment: @Nektoid  Вы писали: "настоящие художники отнюдь не обидчивы". К настоящим себя не отношу, но и обижаться не буду (не продуктивно и вредно это). Может, разберёте меня без осторожничанья?

Comment: Как мне не нравится это "по во́ду"... А так прекрасно! А зачем запятая после *поэта?*

Comment: Думаю, что в поэзии допускается перенос ударения.  Смысл остается ясным, а сочетание даже  приобретает некую необычность и поэтичность.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Спасибо! Так уж вышло с водой, так мы видим :))) А союз И после *поэта* у меня присоединительный.

Comment: Так и подумал, что присоединительный, но не очень хорошо я это понимаю. :(

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец если вы о строфе, то единственное, к чему бы я придрался, — это к рифмам "второй-злой", "зноем-героем", "напишу-прошу". Лучше не рифмовать одинаковые части речи в их одинаковых грамматических формах. Есть, конечно, исключения: например, если рифма строится на изменении парной согласной (кружи-круши), или т. н. "абсолютная рифма" (пальцы-пяльцы), или является явным приёмом ("субъективная акустическая рифма", как у Рождественского: "жадно-жарко"). Но у вас такого нет.

Comment: @Nektoid  Да, спасибо. Знаю, что такие рифмы примитивны. Скажите, а "звуки-муки" сюда разве не попали, или вы их просто не учли? И еще: "напишу-прошу", хоть и слишком похожи по звучанию, но относятся к разным формам: соверш./несоверш. вид, будущее и настоящее время.

Comment: На "звуки-муки" я просто не обратил внимания) Согласен, что 'напишу-прошу' звучит достаточно комфортно, но субъективно я воспринимаю такое как некоторую халтурку, всё-таки невелик труд перестроить глагольную рифму и сделать из 'пишу' 'напишу'. То есть формально грамматическая разница есть, но... Впрочем, не заморачивайтесь, в поэзии я заметно хуже разбираюсь, чем в прозе) Так, нахватался по учебникам кой-чего.

Comment: @Nektoid Да, не простое это дело... А Пушкину, значит, можно было так? :)) В первой же строфе "Онегина": занемог - не мог, наука - скука, коварство - лекарство, себя - тебя; и потом: почтовых - родных, приятель - читатель, мятежной - нежной и т. д.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец разумеется, Пушкину было можно, потому что он писал без малого двести лет назад. Вы полагаете, что поэтическое мастерство двести лет не развивалось? Не надо равняться на классиков — первое правило художника. Надо их читать, слушать, смотреть; надо изучать их методы (что и как они сделали для развития своего вида искусства в историческом контексте), но не равняться на них. Невелик труд писать сейчас "как Пушкин", или сочинять "как Вивальди", или брать олимпийские рекорды столетней давности — но это всё будет ориентация на те планки, которые давным-давно преодолены.

Comment: @Nektoid  Спасибо еще раз! Конечно, вы правы, но полностью сочинять по-новому сейчас не получится, везде будут отголоски и даже заимствования из старого. А я написал это с иронией (улыбочку поставил, а надо было выразить словами).

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец а, простите, не понял :) Дело в том, что заявления начинающих авторов "Пушкин/Толстой/Достоевский так писали, значит, и мы так будем" настолько часты на сайтах для писателей, что у меня уже ответ просто на рефлексе выдаётся)

Comment: @Nektoid АлександрСтрелец  Правильные рифмы – это не главное в поэзии. Стихи не строятся по одним и тем же правилам – иногда рифмы идеальные, а самой поэзии нет.  К тому же  я воспринимаю стихотворение как стилизацию – под Онегинскую строфу, под пушкинский язык и рифмы. Вот это здесь  очаровывает, притягивает, волнует – словно перемещаешься в другое время.

Comment: Душа выбирает  настоящую поэзию как нечто себе родственное, живое, одушевленное, а не  просто составленное из звуков, слов, предложений.  Как выбирает – это, вероятно, тайна. Стихотворение можно улучшить, подкорректировать, но оживить невозможно. Это та грань, которую не перейти.

Comment: @Sharon не главное, но важное. Я сторонник того, что хорошая суть должна быть залита в качественную форму. Бывают, конечно, и формы без сути, но чаще наоборот.

Comment: Качественная форма не помешает, если есть что заливать, я же об этом. Кстати, прозы это тоже в определенной мере касается, только не так явно.  Там тоже должна быть жизнь – писателю важно это изобразить, а читателю увидеть.

Answer (score 3):

Бесщадное зенитное солнце обволокло небольшой старинный поселок, распустило жгучие незримые щупальца и палило, мучило, уничтожало; жуткий зной кипел в каменных двориках, вечерами уютных и шумных, тягуче плыл по узким пустым улицам, раскалял кованые фонари и вывески, нехотя клубился от пролета одуревшей птицы.
Всё, живое и неживое, страдало от жарких объятий светила и ожидало спасительного заката.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма, мне нравится! Картины получились очень живые, реалистичные, разнообразные. Вы использовали и образы из текста, изменив их, а также добавили свои, тоже очень интересные. Желательно обратить внимание на композицию текста: кипящий зной как центральный образ, а тема солнца раскрывается в начале и потом завершает рассказ. Также удачным решением кажется то, что безликий поселок превратился в старинный, так что появились новые возможности для описания. Теперь послушаем и посмотрим, что скажут наши участники. Я очень надеюсь на активное заинтересованное обсуждение и голосование.

Comment: "Два прилагательных при существительном в четыре раза хуже, чем одно. «Усталый пожилой» человек «медленно шел» по направлению к «молоденькой хорошенькой» девушке. Когда я читаю подобное предложение, я надеюсь, что он умрет прежде, чем до нее дотащится. Хотя в таком случае за ним может приехать «стремительная, суетливая» карета скорой помощи. Еще и «оглушительно завывая»" (Аллен Гатри "Все вместе на прополку плеоназмов!").

Comment: @Nektoid
 А как вам такая пара: молодая привлекательная женщина и симпатичный пожилой американец? Или до кого все-таки успеет дотащиться пожилой усатый сержант – до расплывшейся пожилой дамы или до золотистой молодой блондинки?  Тоже плеоназмы на прополку? Что-то мне не хочется составить компанию этому субъекту с иностранной фамилией. Аллен Гатри, редактор издательства Point Blank Press, три года назад написал шуточную статью под названием "Все вместе на прополку плеоназмов!" Этот набор литературных "советов" стал культовым в среде американских авторов.

Comment: @Sharon не громоздить прилагательные и наречия — общее правило писательского мастерства. Просто Гатри хорошо его изложил. // Привлекательная и симпатичный — это плохо, потому что автору надо не констатировать, а описывать. Расплывшаяся пожилая дама спокойно заменяется "матроной". Золотистую молодую блондинку (что за такое вообще описание: золотистая? Она кто, ретривер?) можно описать миллионом способов лучше этого, даже не избавляясь от прилагательных. Например, "блондинка лет двадцати, с загаром столь ровным и оттенка столь аппетитного, будто её окунули в швейцарский шоколад"

Comment: @Nektoid
 Я взяла эти примеры из произведений известных авторов. Зачем давать такую длинную характеристику, если мы просто окинули эту даму беглым взглядом. Мне бы хотелось, чтобы вы конкретно указали лишние прилагательные в конкурсном тексте. Тогда ваша точка зрения будет выглядеть обоснованной. Мне этот текст не кажется менее художественным, чем тот, который в лидеры выбрали вы :)  Или это совершенно невозможно объяснить словами?

Comment: @Sharon я вам уже говорил, что мастерство стиля — лишь одна из характеристик, она может отсутствовать даже у великих, например у Л. Толстого. // "Бесщадное зенитное солнце" — хорошо, хотя две кряду столь яркие, небанальные характеристики — немного перебор, как по мне. А вот дальше... "Небольшой старинный" — перебор, "жгучие незримые" — перебор, "узким пустым" — перебор. Сравните с тем, как у FlossyU: "плотный и потный воздух" — два прилагательных, но тут и образность, и аллитерация, и незатёртость. "Зной... клубился от пролета одуревшей птицы" — а от пролёта неодуревшей не клубился, ок.

Comment: @Sharon надеюсь, я обосновал свой минус этому ответу? Разумеется, это личное мнение, я никого ничему не учу насильно, никому ничего не доказываю и никому ничего не навязываю.

Comment: Римма, плюс!....

Comment: @Nektoid Ладно, спасибо, спорить не буду, хотя не все понимаю. А потный воздух – это влажный или вызывающий пот? Я не помню, чтобы в долгую жару воздух был влажным, но именно это слышится вначале. Зной клубился от полета одуревшей птицы... Здесь, как я думаю, емкая информация, зачем видеть ее искаженной? Ну и т..д. Ну что ж, мы ведь в мастерской писателей не учились, вот и не умеем ни хорошо писать, ни правильно критиковать.

Comment: @Sharon я ж говорил, что не хочу в конкурсе участвовать. И сидели бы вы тут спокойненько, хвалили бы друг друга. В следующий раз будьте осмотрительнее в приглашениях.

Comment: @Nektoid Я думаю, что ваша критика оказалась очень кстати, большое вам спасибо  за участие. Мне казалось, что все наши прозаические тексты, конечно,  разные, но все-таки примерно одного уровня,  так что меня удивило только ваше предпочтение кого-либо.

Comment: @Nektoid Перечитываю еще раз текст. Предложение (1) – довольно банально. Дуновение ветерка – это ясно, но почему в паре со струйкой воздуха. Про потный воздух я уже говорила, он все-таки иссушает и забирает влагу. Дальше детали. Так дождь был недавно? Ну про мошкару, наверное, неплохо, только таких картинок мне видеть не приходилось. Ну а образ бабы Вали, если  ее сравнить с образом у Рождественского (дышит лихорадочно и жадно), явно проигрывает ему и не впечатляет никак, а места занимает много.

Comment: @Sharon "В начале сотворил Бог небо и землю. Земля же была безвидна и пуста..." — так начинается Библия. Считается, что Бог сначала создал ex nihilo первоматерию, вот эту безвидную землю, а потом из неё уже лепил всё остальное. Я писал в комментариях к варианту Флосси, что тот текст "больше других похож на художественную литературу". Это не значит, что он идеален, это значит, что там имеется первоматерия, массив, с которым можно работать. А вот этот текст, на мой взгляд, улучшить сложнее, чем переписать.

Comment: @Nektoid  Жаль, что я ничего этого не вижу, никакой первоматерии. По мне, так все банально, неточно, случайно. так дети пишут школьные сочинения.  И ни одного содержательно комментария, ни одного впечатления  от наших участников.  Наверное, тоже не увидели ничего особенного. Мне хочется  вам поверить, но я не верю...

Comment: @Sharon не верьте, кто ж заставляет)) К тому же творчество штука такая, что даже экспертные отзывы не могут быть лишены субъективности. А я далеко не эксперт, просто чуть больше среднено знаю о том, как устроена литература.

Comment: @Nektoid А можете переделать эту "первоматерию",  чтобы мы на конкретном примере тоже научились  видеть скрытые достоинства и поняли, как устроена литература. Это не очень сложная задача?

Comment: @Sharon https://i.imgur.com/qtGSlKt.png

Comment: @Nektoid Спасибо! Отзыв (общее впечатление от текста) можно сюда написать?

Comment: @Sharon пожалуйста.

Comment: Образ стал более емким, понятным, обозначенным, но краски художника резкие и  грубые: нещадно, вылакал, выпарил, мечется, мошкара, ковыляет, насосался, по-вампирьи, сырь. Изображенная действительность некрасива и враждебна, так что даже кошачьи плошки хочется пнуть ногой. Нет  здесь ни понимания, ни терпения,  ни ожидания перемен к лучшему.
Что это? Раздражение измученного жестокой жарой человека?  Или общее недовольство жизнью, ее бессмысленностью и несовершенством?

Comment: @Sharon раздражение жарой) Оттого и первые два предложения краткие, рубленые, как сквозь зубы; а потом прорывает. (Пнуть ногой — плеоназм, чем ещё можно пнуть, кроме как ногой? :))

Comment: В исходном тексте ничего этого не было, там только описания – простые наблюдения,  этюды, зарисовки из блокнота.   Как это можно считать художественной литературой и видеть  там первоматерию. Ваша доработка никак не выражает настроения автора – впрочем, там и не было никакого настроения.  А плеоназм тоже бывает нужен - для равновесия фразы. Никогда не думали об этом?

Comment: @Sharon хорошо-хорошо, пусть так) // Есть способы уравновесить фразу, не вкорячивая в неё сорное слово.

Comment: @Nektoid Есть способ закончить светскую или дружескую беседу, "не вкорячивая" в нее грубое просторечие. Или мне на вашу дружественность уже не стоит рассчитывать,ага?  :)

Comment: @Sharon наоборот: чем дружественнее я отношусь к человеку, тем всё более странные лики из богатой коллекции своей шизофренической натуры к нему обращаю)

Comment: Спасибо!  Вот здорово! А то я уже вся "распечалилась".

Comment: @Sharon и все: жалкое общение у нас тут, увы.

Comment: @Артём Луговой
Вы это о чем, Артем?

Comment: Не догадываетесь? Плохо, что мы не знаем, как кто выглядит, не хватает живого общения. Хотя бы голосом.

Comment: @Артём Луговой  В карнавале масок тоже есть свои плюсы.  Здесь мы просто Homo sapiens  и не отвлекаемся на внешние факторы. У Емца есть описание высокоразвитой цивилизации, где живые существа вообще не имеют формы, а выбирают любую по необходимости. Для них долгое постоянство формы очень опасно, иначе из нее можно вообще не выйти. Вот как у нас, землян. Расширяйте сознание, старайтесь меняться – полезное упражнение :)

Comment: Это всё заумь для меня, мне это не интересно. ;)

Comment: @Артём Луговой Ну хорошо, а вы не пробовали общаться в социальных сетях? Там очень живое общение и без зауми: семейные фотографии, любимые кошечки-собачки и все такое. :)  Кроме того, многие люди избегают публичности, иногда им это просто не положено по статусу их работы (или есть другие причины) А здесь они чувствуют себя свободно, раскованно...

Comment: @Sharon: со второй половиной согласен, действительно, таким людям тут удобно, раз за них.

Comment: @Артём Луговой Интересно, а здесь можно записать голос и поместить на личную страницу.

Answer (score 2):

Предложу банальный вариант исправления. Боюсь, что вы и так догадались до него и почему-то считаете его плохим.

*На улицах небольшого посёлка кипел жуткий зной, давно уже погрузивший в свои жаркие объятия пустующие улицы скромного поселения.*

Или так:

*Небольшой посёлок был словно объят пламенем, редкие пешеходы страдали от невообразимого зноя.*

Сильно исказил смысл, не годится? Или ничего? Зато избавился от повтора не только с улицами, но и с посёлком/поселением.

**На конкурс:**

*На улочках родной деревушки всё расплавлялось от нестерпимой жары — горящий диск солнца, казалось, вышел из орбит и пытался испепелить всё вокруг. Сочная трава пожухла, зачахла, цветы склонили свои пышные головы, птичий концерт смолк — лишь ворона изредка каркнет издевательски — и тишина. Сплетничающие соседки тоже куда-то все попрятались, а пешеход, если какой и попадался, еле волочил ноги, прибитый и усталый, мечтая поскорее добраться до дому, умыться, напиться.*

**Критика:**

Варианты Надежды и Нектоида мне очень нравятся, однако один непонятный момент я заметил у Надежды.

*...изгоняла всё живое с опустевших дорог* — если дороги опустели, то изгонять было уже некого/нечего. Нестыковка во времени.

Comment: Артем,  спасибо за ответ (лайк  за внимание и участие).  Грамматика отчасти исправлена, но не стилистика (есть повтор слов). Но нравится ли вам самим ваш вариант?  Вы  бы так написали?  Образ понятен, но перегружен деталями, да и подбор слов неудачен, а мне еще и фонетика  не нравится (все эти Ж и З).  И слово "погрузить"  характерно  для технических х текстов. Претензия на оригинальность есть, а художественный вкус как раз отсутствует.

Comment: Вы так покритиковали его, что теперь совсем не нравится.))) А где повтор слов? Улицы?

Comment: Ну да, улицы.  В одном и том же предложении такой повтор считается стилистической ошибкой.

Comment: Редкие пешеходы страдали, а остальные пешеходы не страдали) Здесь та же возможность разночтения прилагательного, как во фразе "редкая птица долетит до середины Днепра" (то есть попугай долетит, страус долетит, а птица, которая не редкая -- чайка или соловей -- не долетят).

Comment: Ну что вы, Nektoid, простите, несёте за чушь!))) Как можно так докапываться! Пешеходы таки не птицы. ;)

Comment: Не только можно, но и нужно, в этом и работа редактора)) К тому же чем лучше текст, тем глубже докапывание.

Comment: Да, но "редкие пешеходы" нельзя понять иначе. @Sharon: а вы не прокомментировали мой второй вариант.

Comment: @Nektoid: вы забыли проголосовать за вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, Артем, за вариант, я  вашей правки и вашего диалога просто не видела. Но мне надо подумать, чуть позже отвечу.

Comment: @Артём Луговой
Ну что ж, товарищ автор, давайте и вас покритикуем :). Итак, ваш вариант: "Небольшой посёлок был словно объят пламенем, редкие пешеходы страдали от невообразимого зноя". «Словно объят пламенем» – сравнение новым не назовешь, это уже речевой штамп, так что надо его доработать. (К тому же пламя желто-оранжевого цвета, а здесь этого нет.) "Редкие пешеходы страдали от невообразимого зноя" – слишком общая фраза, а хотелось бы увидеть, как они конкретно страдают, мучаются.

Comment: Поэтому предлагаю такую доработку вашего варианта: Небольшой посёлок был словно объят прозрачно-мерцающим пламенем, а нестерпимо жгучий зной заполнял пустующие улицы. (Возражения против критики принимаются и приветствуются.)

Comment: @Sharon: неплохо, только плохо представляю себепрозрачно-мерцающий пламень...

Comment: Как это не представляете? Воздух прозрачный, невидимый, но перегретый воздух колеблется, мерцает, дрожит; так же колеблется и пламя. Но вы можете использовать то определение, которое вам нравится, но оно должно быть необычным, футуристическим, например. То есть должно придавать  свежесть восприятия вашей метафоре.

Comment: Мне не понравится кот в мешке.))))))

Comment: @Артём Луговой
Артем, а где же ваш текст в начале ответа с пометкой "на конкурс". Пожалуйста, напишите.  И еще было бы хорошо, если вы добавили критику по уже данным вариантам.  Ведь многие наши литераторы только критикой и занимались, у них к этому был талант.  Мне кажется, что критиковать еще интереснее, чем писать. :) Ну пожалуйста...

Comment: Надо подумать, не знаю, смогу ли что-то придумать годное...

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой хороший финал (вот это "добраться-умыться-напиться"), но остальное, на мой взгляд, не так хорошо. Например, *цветы склонили свои обычно пышные благоухающие головы* — спасибо за уточнение, что склонили именно свои головы, а то ведь могли склонить чужие :) Вообще говоря, всё ваше описание отдаёт никак не деревенской мощью, это скорее про поселение в тропиках. Какие вы слова используете? Изумрудная, пышные, благоухающие, разноцветные птицы, извилистые ветви... Индиана Джонс, а не упомянутая в начале вашего текста *деревушка*.

Comment: @Nektoid: спасибо за критику! Хорошо, что что-то хоть вам понравилось.)) Насчёт своих голов мне кажется, что иногда и без местоимения понятно, о чём речь, в нём нет необходимости, но с ним складнее звучит и поэтому оно не выглядит избыточным. Затрудняюсь сказать какую, но определённую функцию оно выполняет. Что касается того, подходит это деревне или нет, возможно, вы и правы, сложно мне понять это до конца, однако в свою защиту скажу, что ухоженные садики с пышными садовыми цветами могут быть и у жителей деревушки, изумрудная трава может быть и там же, и в поле.

Comment: Извилистые ветви могут быть вполне и у деревьев в нашей матушке России. Разноцветные птицы? Тропикам очень подходит, согласен. Но разве не может быть и у нас многообразия птиц разной окраски? Посмотрел, *изумрудная трава* в Нацкорпусе два раза встречается у писателей в первой половине прошлого века (и один раз в нынешнем).

Comment: @Артём Луговой дело не столько в значении отдельных слов, сколько в том, какую картину они рисуют в целом. Схожие коннотации имеют свойство притягиваться друг к другу, и если по отдельности разноцветные птицы или пышные цветы в деревеньке вполне возможны (а вот "извилистые" мне не кажется впихуемым в картину никак), то в сочетании это уже создаёт атмосферу тропиков.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой а, не заметил третьего вашего комментария. Да, я поставил.

Comment: Спасибо! Отвечу вам тем же)

Comment: @Артём Луговой только я не за конкурсный ваш вариант поставил, а за наблюдательность -- что заметили нестыковку во варианте уважаемой Надежды))

Comment: Ха-ха, интересно))

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Артем, НАМНОГО ЛУЧШЕ, вот пусть и N. скажет! Структуру исправили, теперь – «пиши, сокращай» (информативный принцип). Поищите «лишние» слова; я бы убрала: считанные, загрустили, благоухавшие, великолепный – они рисуют совсем другую картину (противопоставление здесь будет лишним). «Считанные» – жара, скорее всего, стояла давно, это гроза налетает в считанные минуты. И чем больше конкретики и меньше пафоса, тем лучше.  Ведь и художник, изображая такую картину, не будет использовать яркие краски. (При описаниях очень удобно сравнение литературы с живописью.) Перед «и тишина» – тире.

Comment: Очень рад, спасибо!) Если "считанные" убрать, тогда и "часы" надо чем-то заменить, или нет?

Comment: Да, конечно, все сочетание надо просто убрать, ничем не заменяя. Не стоит перегружать текст информацией.

Comment: Артём, спасибо за то, что обратили на это внимание (опустевшие - изгоняла)! И впрямь нелогично.)

Comment: Не за что, Надежда!)

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, здесь одна метафора перебивает другую. Сначала образ воды, а потом объятий. Я бы убрала один из образов. *На улицах небольшого посёлка кипел жуткий зной, окуная в свое жаркое марево пустующие улицы скромного поселения.*
Но раз тут конкурс... Я, как всякий уважающий себя графоман, конечно, попытаюсь что-то написать, при этом я постараюсь сохранить изначальную метафору.
**На конкурс:**
*На улицах небольшого города кипел зной. Жара безжалостно изгоняла все живое с опустевших дорог. Ничто не смело нарушить власти беспощадно сияющего солнца - ни ветерок, ни тень, ни дождевая капля. Даже птицы, спрятавшиеся глубоко в ветвях, не тратили силы на пение и, казалось, боялись лишний раз пискнуть.*

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Мне, честно говоря, уже больше ничего не нравится в этой метафоре, так что по деталям и разбирать сложно. Хочется все зачеркнуть и записать заново. Единственное, что привлекает, это сочетание "кипел жуткий зной". Почему он казался кипящим? Как мы зрительно воспринимаем эту перегретую воздушную среду? Она становится плотной, колеблется? "Кипит", выплескивается на улицы. разливается по ним? Как обо всем этом рассказать в одном предложении, чтобы читатель почувствовал эту нестерпимую жару. Напишите на конкурс что-нибудь свое, так, мне кажется. будет лучше.  Спасибо!

Comment: Именно! Двоящийся образ, как я называю. Воду, жидкость можно сравнить с объятиями тоже (океан обнял меня), но здесь получается какое-то вложение образа в образ, стилистическое нагромождение.

Comment: Sharon, а мне нравится образ, и он вполне вызывает у меня нужные ощущения - вспоминаются улочки в Средней Азии в самую жару. Я лично вижу "густую" жару, от которой воздух дрожит, колеблется (особенно у асфальта). Поэтому она и кипит. Может быть, сделать так: На улицах небольшого посёлка кипел жуткий зной. Улицы опустели.

Comment: Nektoid, согласна. Образы не должны конфликтовать.

Comment: Образ "кипящего зноя"неплохой, его можно использовать. Я тоже представляю, как дрожит перегретый воздух. Но в такой короткой фразе нет реального ощущения этой невыносимой жары, нет присутствия персонажа, его чувств, эмоций, а есть только зрительные впечатления отстраненного наблюдателя.  Также повтор "на улицах" желательно убрать.

Comment: @Sharon а в оригинальном предложении и нет персонажа. Был бы персонаж — было бы смысл разбирать метафоры ещё и с этой точки зрения, потому что метафоры "танцуются" от персонажа. То, как ощущает мир гик-айтишник, сильно отличается от того, как ощущает мир деревенский подросток. На мой взгляд, рамки конкурсного задания чрезмерно расплывчаты, поэтому я участвовать не стану)

Comment: А я и не настаиваю на персонаже, он там не нужен, вы меня не совсем поняли. Просто в реальном предложении создан только зрительный образ, мне он кажется отвлеченным.  Но это всего лишь мое мнение, а вы думаете по-другому.  Я же сказал - полная свобода! Выбирайте любой стиль и любую форму. Поэтому, пожалуйста, не отказываетесь, я очень на вас рассчитывала. К тому же я постараюсь, чтобы выбор соответствовал не моим вкусам, а мнению большинства. Пожалуйста, поддержите "мероприятие", у нас не так часто они проводятся.

Comment: @Sharon ну ок, мой вариант: *Нонеча в деревне жарынь!* :)

Comment: Спасибо, мне нравится!  Юмор, конечно же, приветствуется! Если еще немного подробностей, то у вас будет несомненный успех. Ну добавьте еще хотя бы одно предложение и запишите к конце своего ответа.  Спасибо!!

Comment: @Sharon ну да, ну да, "рассупонилось солнышко, расталдыкнуло свои лучи по белу светушку")

Comment: Вот, вот, именно это я и имела в виду :))

Comment: @Sharon хорошо, я вынес свой вариант в начало своего ответа)

Comment: @Sharon, да, два раза про улицы нехорошо. Я попыталась развить изначальную метафору про кипящий зной, раз у нас тут конкурс.)  Внесла изменение в свой ответ, добавила вариант.

Comment: На мой взгляд, ваш вариант не очень корректен с точки зрения стилистики, но не знаю, можно ли делать разбор конкурсного текста. Да и уместно ли вообще критикой заниматься.

Comment: @ Nadezhda, Nektoid Да, я видела, спасибо вам за участие в конкурсе. Я, как и договаривались, комментировать ничего не буду, а вот КРИТИКУ хотелось бы услышать, это тоже очень ИНТЕРЕСНО, но как? Может быть, к конце вашего собственного ответа добавить что-нибудь вроде "Критика конкурсных вариантов". Или такие ответы с разбором можно вообще давать как самостоятельные отзывы, даже если там нет конкурсного текста (и вам, и всем остальным). Как думаете, товарищи участники? Тогда я добавлю информацию об этом в свой ответ.

Comment: @Nektoid, А вы мой вариант прокомментируйте, который я давала на другом ресурсе. Что скажете? Он, конечно, не конкурсный, но я же старалась написать что-нибудь приличное...  Вы не стесняйтесь, я художественную критику люблю, в отличие от грамматической.

Comment: @Sharon это который в вопросе вариант или тот, который в ответе-сообщении о конкурсе?

Comment: В самом вопросе не мой вариант, чужой. Мне он не понравился, хотя получил три голоса. А мой вариант в  ответе-сообщении  "О конкурсе".

Comment: Nektoid, Sharon, критика - это интересно! Критикуйте, конечно.

Comment: @Nadezhda если кратко, чтобы влезло в комментарий, то: 1) *небольшого города* — лучше избегать повторения слога на стыке слов ("го-го" в данном случае). 2) *безжалостно изгоняла; беспощадно сияющего* — лучше искать такое прилагательное, которое не потребует к себе наречия. Прилагательное без наречия, глагол без прилагательного — так пишется ёмкий текст. Продолжение ниже.

Comment: @Nadezhda 3) Не надо перечислять, чего не было (тень, ветерок и т. п.), потому что читатель всё это представит, это реакция мозга на слова. Лучше писать то, что было. "Вокруг не было никакого леса" — плохо. "Мы скакали по голой степи" — хорошо. 4) Тени не было нигде, но внезапно возникли деревья с птицами глубоко в ветвях. Если есть деревья, то есть и какая-никакая тень, хотя бы под ними.

Comment: @ Nektoid Жаль, что тут нет цитирования, неудобно. Спасибо за критику! Небольшого города - нет повторения, потому что произносим не звук /г/, а /в/ - /ова/.  Ёмкий текст я не хотела, мне, наоборот, хотелось проявить щедрость в описании.)  Но вот про перечисление теней и прочего - согласна ,я и сама об этом думала, когда писала, - не собьет ли это читателя с настроя на жару.

Answer (score 2):

**Мой внеконкурсный ответ:**

*В небольшом поселке стояла нестерпимая жара. Красный кирпичный особняк в центре площади казался раскаленным, а солнце неподвижно сияло над ним, как желтая огненная лава. Серая густая пыль покрыла деревья и траву, будто смешала их с асфальтом.
Вокруг не было ни души. Всё живое затихло, спряталось, затаилось, и только горячий воздух растекался по опустевшим улицам.*

**Цитаты из классиков**

(1) **Я такой жары ещё не помню...** Жарко паутине. Жарко полдню. Жарко сквозняку, дыханью, шагу. Жарко...

Кажутся несбыточными грозы. И собака, будто после кросса, дышит лихорадочно и жадно. Жарко... (Р. Рождественский).

(2) Улица была совершенно пуста. Дома были все одинаковые, белые, двухэтажные, и казалось, что в них нет ни души; белая густая пыль лежала на мостовой; и **все это слепило, все было залито жарким, пламенным … солнцем.** (И. Бунин).

(3) …безумие и ужас.  Впервые я почувствовал это, когда мы шли по энской дороге, — шли десять часов не останавливаясь... **Стоял зной**. Не знаю, сколько было градусов: сорок, пятьдесят или больше; знаю только, что он был непрерывен, безнадежно-ровен и глубок. **Солнце было так огромно, так огненно и страшно**, как будто земля приблизилась к нему и скоро сгорит в этом беспощадном огне… **Раскаленный воздух дрожал, и беззвучно, точно готовые потечь, дрожали камни…** А иссушающий, палящий жар проникал в самую глубину тела, в кости и в мозг (Л. Андреев).

Comment: Я старался, хоть словечко-то скажите)

Comment: 1. Жара *стояла*, особняк *казался*, солнце *сияло*, поэтому лучше "пыль покрывала", а не "пыль покрыла". При этом совершенный глагол "смешала" можно оставить в таком виде, но лучше "смешивала". 2. Сравнение солнца просто с лавой, на мой взгляд, не очень, всё-таки лава — что-то текучее. "А солнце неподвижно сияло над ним, как котёл с лавой" — так было бы получше. 3. Чисто "звуковой" нюанс: лучше избегать ряда возвратных глаголов, они создают неприятный шелест своими окончаниями: я про "спряталось, затаилось, ...растекался).

Comment: 1. Пыль уже покрыла - сов. вид.  2. Сравнение солнце с лавой - это очень хорошее сравнение. Мне Яндекс такую картинку поставил: красная вулканическая гора, а из нее выплескивается лава, выглядит как солнце один к одному. 3. Это не "неприятный шелест", а звукопись. Приятно так шипит, как змея. :))

Comment: @Sharon дело, конечно, ваше. Я никогда никому не доказываю ничего в плане стилистики :)

Comment: @Артём Луговой
Про ваш вариант?  Но я вроде бы не критикую конкурсантов до окончания конкурса. А потом да, конечно.

Comment: @Nektoid  Да ладно, это я так, в шутку, чтобы с вами поговорить... Но про картинку я правду говорю, солнце очень похоже на лаву. И про звукопись скажите: то это художественный прием, а то неприятно звучит. Как тут разобраться?

Comment: @Sharon солнце похоже не на просто лаву, а на лаву, выплескивающуюся из вулкана. У вас же оно находится в зените, вокруг ничего нет. То есть образ не доработан. Что касается звукописи: мне кажется, она была бы уместна в перечислении, то есть если бы вместо "затихло" был ещё возвратный глагол, то это был бы приём. А вот "растекался", который уже о другом повествует, а не о спрятавшихся-затаившихся, визуально как бы прилагает образ к перечислению, но он-то уже другой. // Немного утрируя: практически все правила стилистики относительны. Но чтобы понять, какое и когда можно нарушить, нужен опыт.

Comment: Ага, про мой вариант. Ну просто скажите, вам хоть немножко он понравился?)

Comment: А разве звукописи не все равно, к какой грамматике относится слово? Это же просто звуки, которые мы слышим, и они так "красиво" повторяются. А у вас звуки связывают слова? Но вам, наверное,  виднее...  Как все-таки трудно быть правильным писателем :)

Comment: @Sharon В языковой прозе всё должно быть в балансе, все слои и все между ними взаимосвязи учитываются)) Конечно, я со своей колокольни смотрю. В жёсткой боевой фантастике, к примеру, совсем иные принципы конструкции текста.

Comment: Артем, по содержанию вариант очень неплохой, но форму нужно доработать. У вас текст получился монотонный, однообразный.  Нужно, чтобы смысловые образы имели разную грамматику, были неожиданные переходы. Разнообразие нравится читателю,  ему нужны меняющиеся картинки.  Попробуйте сами поэкспериментировать, или я попробую после, ОК?

Comment: @Nektoid А вот ваши любимые авторы что же, всегда безупречны, во всем совершенны? Вы у них видите какие-нибудь неточности, ошибки?

Comment: @Sharon неточности и ошибки есть у всех и всегда, совершенства нет :) Если бы был совершенный автор, я бы читал только его. Есть ещё и немаловажный фактор вкуса: что одному хорошо, то другой написал бы иначе. Мне кажется, немало писателей стали таковыми именно из-за того, что не могли найти для себя идеального автора. Они вынуждены были начать писать сами, поскольку никто за них не писал так, чтобы им хватило :)

Comment: Хорошо быть оригинальным автором, тогда пусть с меня пример берут... Одним дано создавать новые формы, а другим  – доводить их до совершенства в мелких деталях. Так, наверное, во всем, а не только в литературе.

Comment: Подредактировал я свой вариант, Шарон. Лучше?

Comment: Артем, посмотрите мой  комментарий в вашем вопросе.

Comment: @Nektoid  У меня к вам еще вопрос. Вот, к примеру, вы читаете мой текст и делаете мне три замечания. Допустим, я соглашаюсь и исправляю их. Разве мой ответ стал намного лучше? Но допустим, что некоторые замечания СУЩЕСТВЕННО меняют текст. Автор все исправляет, и текст становится по качеству уровнем выше. Но вот ШЕДЕВРОМ он вряд ли станет, а мне-то хочется, чтобы стал именно шедевром. Получается, что в нем отсутствует нечто главное, что исправить нельзя? И никто не скажет, в чем заключается это главное. Это Тайна, нам это недоступно увидеть?

Comment: Но хотя бы существенность замечаний мы можем оценить? Рассмотрим это  на наших примерах. Вот делаются замечания, а я сразу вижу, что текст намного лучше не станет.  Есть более важные недостатки, так, может быть, критик должен видеть именно их в первую очередь и указывать на них.

Comment: @Sharon главное — это всё-таки опыт, а опыт — это знание тысячи и одного мелкого нюанса, небольшого правила и понимание, что где когда применять. Вряд ли можно сразу сделать шедевр, за один скачок. Обычно требуется многослойная "дошлифовка", каждый этап которой опирается на предыдущий... И всё равно шедевра не будет, и всё равно автору рано или поздно надо сказать себе "хватит". Просто потому, что чем дальше шлифовка, тем менее она заметна для непрофессионала (а потом и для профессионала), но тем более требует сил. Главное — не завязнуть в тексте, но и не сказать "хватит" слишком рано.

Comment: Хорошо, давайте ближе к примерам. Вот ваша правка исходного предложения (вариант 3): На улицах небольшого посёлка не было ни души: по ним кипятком струился зной.  Что, оно стало намного лучше., я так не думаю. Не честнее ли сказать автору, что его предложение (особенно вторую часть) нужно почти полностью изменить.  А лучше выбросить все предложение и записать по-другому, потому что никакие правки ему не помогут. Или второй вопрос: вы можете существенно изменить мое предложение, поднять его на качественно новый уровень? Мелкие замечания ему мало что дадут.

Comment: @Sharon мой третий вариант — это просто правильно написанное проходное, информативное предложение. Боевая фантастика, к примеру, почти вся из таких состоит, так как там акцент на события, а не на искристость образов. // Насчёт существенного изменения (я так понимаю, речь идёт о внеконкурсном варианте в этом ответе?) — где граница существенности? Полная переработка — это написание заново, но редактору этого следует избегать, потому что как нельзя прожить за человека жизнь, так нельзя за него написать его текст. Можно написать свой. Но не его.

Comment: Существенность имеет предел, дальше него мы намеренно не двинемся.  Выйти на более высокий уровень и создать шедевр можно  только с помощью высших сил (вдохновения, подсознания). И если текст близок к существенному пределу, то его лучше оставить в покое и назвать нормальным вариантом, вот я о чем говорю.

Comment: @Sharon о нет, всё наоборот)) Сперва вдохновение, а потом шлифовка. Вдохновение — это вневременной укол информации, часто несловесной, в виде эстетической эмоции (то есть слитых воедино мысли и чувства). А задача автора — этот вневременной укол развернуть во времени (или в пространстве, если речь не о книге или музыке, а о картине). И вот тут уже нужен профессионализм. Деятель искусства — это зачастую *переводчик* с вневременного на земной язык.

Answer (score 2):

**На конкурс**: *Сегодня солнце пекло нещадно, ни малейшего дуновения ветерка, ни прохладной струйки воздуха ждать неоткуда. Вокруг только плотный и потный воздух, который, казалось, иссушал всё: лужи после недавнего дождя затянулись пухом с деревьев и пылью, окрасившись в асфальтовый серый, в плошке для животных, где еще вчера на донышке была вода, роится и толкается обезумевшая от жажды мошкара… Даже поры морщинистой кожи бабы Вали, которая шла к колодцу, были лишены влаги, то ли из-за почтенного возраста, то ли из-за удушающего зноя, то ли из-за всего вместе.*

Comment: FlossyU,  редко вы отвечаете на вопросы. Рад, что присоединились!

Comment: Спасибо за ваше участие. Приятно, когда люди активны. У каждого автора есть что-то свое, интересное и оригинальное,  и порой эти наблюдения не хуже, чем у известных писателей. Надеюсь, что наши участники  прокомментирую ваш вариант.

Comment: Из всех вариантов этот больше других похож на художественную литературу. Тем не менее я вижу ряд ошибок. 1. Скачки времён глаголов неверно обставлены: где следовало бы поставить двоеточия, стоят запятые. 2. *лужи после недавнего дождя затянулись пухом...* — можно прочитать двояко: и что лужи образовались вследствие недавнего дождя, и что лужи затянулись пухом вследствие недавнего дождя. 3. *были лишены* — некрасивый повтор слога на стыке слов. 4. На мой вкус, *почтенного* тут выпадает из стиля текста. 5. *шла к колодцу* — слишком плоско. Лучше найти глагол покрасочнее: *ковыляла*, например.

Comment: @Nektoid  Вы меня заинтриговали. :)  А на что же тогда похожи варианты других участников, вы могли бы подобрать для них походящее определение?  Я примерно догадываюсь на что, но хотелось бы услышать от вас. Как все-таки отличить художественную литературы от нехудожественной? Неужели  это можно сделать по короткому фрагменту текста. Можно коротко, буквально пару слов.  Кстати, если перечитать цитаты наших великих и известных, у них  реальные наблюдения действительности  просматриваются через общий художественный образ, а не просто перечисляются.  Идет тщательный отбор реалий, как мне кажется.

Comment: @Sharon не всегда, но чаще всего можно буквально по одному абзацу понять, художественный ли текст или по каким-то причинам до этого звания не дотягивает. Замечу, что "нехудожественный" ни в коем разе не означает автоматически, что "не талантливый", это означает, что автор пока не понимает, не чувствует каких-то объективных вещей. Именно объективных, а то многие любят говорить, что художественность текста — вещь сугубо субъективная. Нет, не сугубо. Объективные вещи — это те, что связаны с человеческим мозгом и тем, как именно он воспринимает текст и переводит в представление.

Comment: @Nektoid Я увидела в выбранном вами отрывке записи внимательного натуралиста (и это тоже прекрасно), но в чем вы видите здесь особую художественность. Я считала, что художественный образ всегда обобщенный, что он передает нам нечто большее, чем то, что сказано словами. В нем отражается многомерная реальность, которую мы с помощью наших органов чувств неспособны воспринять – нечто невыразимое.  Художник рассказывает нам о верхнем (горнем, космическом) мире, доступном только подсознанию.

Comment: @Nektoid Вы сейчас говорите о деталях художественного творчества (это тоже важно и интересно), но я пока еще не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду под самим художественным творчеством. И мне несправедливой кажется ваша оценка, то есть выделение одной работы среди всех прочих. Возможно, вы правы, но я не понимаю почему.

Comment: @Sharon иногда образ — это просто образ)) А иногда и вовсе случайность. https://vk.com/wall-129239055_151457 // Зачастую никаких горних миров нет и быть не должно. Вот вам Чейз — чаще всего в его детективах всё сугубо материалистично: имеется некая внушительная сумма на кону, имеются некие препятствия к её получению. Всё, коллизия есть, чё ещё надо. Никаких душевных страданий героев. Книги могут опираться на любую из ступеней пирамиды Маслоу, и ясно, что книги, опирающиеся на нижние ступени, грубее и проще, но и понятнее.

Comment: @Sharon что касается данного текста, то можете считать мой отзыв субъективщиной :)

Comment: Эти миры в нашей душе.  Реальность – это одно, а то, что мы видим и чувствуем, воспринимая самые обыденные детали жизни, это совсем другое. Что касается вашего отзыва, то я его так и понимаю, да еще подозреваю вас в нечестной игре. :) Это, конечно, шутка, ведь мне совсем не хочется расстаться с таким интересным собеседником, как вы. Тут просматривается тонкая психология ситуаций, которая влияет на наши поступки. Жаль, что вы мало читаете  Емца – у него есть великолепная сцена на тему "обидеть художника может каждый".  Знаете, настоящие художники очень обидчивы...

Comment: @Sharon настоящие художники отнюдь не обидчивы) А вот графоманы... Уж поверьте, я сталкивался с достаточным количеством и тех, и других, чтобы собрать статистику. Но, кроме того, слишком глубокой критикой можно сломать начинающего художника. Поэтому-то я, как говорил где-то выше, почти всегда критикую на один слой шлифовки выше, чем есть у художника сейчас. А не на два и не на три. Тут уж лучше состорожничать.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за беседу, вам. как говорится, виднее.  Вероятно, мы с вами люди из разных миров, с разных планет и поэтому недостаточно понимаем друг друга.  Как легко вы говорите: вот этот настоящий художник, а этот графоман. Это художественное произведение, а это школьное сочинение.  И каждое утверждение как аксиома, доказательств не требуется...

Comment: @Sharon у меня в профиле написано: "Все мои ответы субъективны, а не истина в последней инстанции". К комментариям это тоже относится.

Answer (score 1):

**Описание конкурса**

Я уже отвечала на этот вопрос на другом ресурсе, и вот мой ответ:
Предложение является сложной метафорой, но она реализована непоследовательно, то есть отдельные детали не создают впечатления единого законченного образа. Вариант правки: ***В небольшом поселке кипел жуткий полуденный зной, растекаясь по пустующим улицам.***

Сначала этот вариант меня вполне устраивал, но потом стал казаться слишком умозрительным и особых эмоций и сочувствия не вызывал. А можно ли вообще в двух-трех предложениях изобразить невыносимую жару, пекло, чтобы вызвать у читателя такие же ощущения?

Я перечитала начало «Мастера и Маргариты», в очередной раз позавидовав «изобразительной силе таланта» Иванушки Бездомного:

«*Трудно сказать, что именно подвело Ивана Николаевича – **изобразительная ли сила его таланта** или полное незнакомство с вопросом, по которому он собирался писать, – но Иисус в его изображении получился **ну совершенно как живой**, хотя и не привлекающий к себе персонаж*».

**И еще цитаты**: «*В тот час, когда уж, кажется, и сил не было дышать, когда солнце, раскалив Москву, в сухом тумане валилось куда-то за Садовое кольцо… И тут знойный воздух сгустился перед ним, и соткался из этого воздуха прозрачный гражданин престранного вида*…»

**Итак, конкурс!** У наших писателей полная свобода. Можно взять исходный образ и структуру предложения, а можно написать что-то свое и даже изменить объем текста (в разумных пределах). Интересные цитаты из других произведений тоже приветствуются и дополнительно учитываются при голосовании.

Я уже комментировала три ответа и больше вмешиваться не буду. Более того, вам **не стоит ориентироваться на мое мнение**, мое участие в выборе победителя будет минимальным. Мне даже нравится все **самое неожиданное** и отличное от моего представления, ведь и собственный ответ меня не устроил. Можно изменить место действия, можно ввести любого наблюдателя – даже Волка с Лисой, им ведь тоже жарко:))

Поэтому я очень надеюсь на ваше участие и поддержку, то есть на голосование и комментарии. **Давайте все вместе выберем нашего «народного писателя».**

Если вы уже отвечали на вопрос, то в начале его дайте окончательный вариант с пометкой «ответ для конкурса».

Удачи вам!

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 14.04.2022**

Если вы не хотите участвовать в конкурсе как писатель, то можно, как я думаю, в ответе написать **критику** предложенных вариантов или **цитаты** из классиков с описанием жары. Это тоже было бы прекрасно и познавательно, и за такие ответы можно получить голоса наших участников.

Comment: Не лучше сказать "**в** очередной раз"?

Comment: Спасибо, исправлено.

Comment: *В небольшом поселке кипел жуткий полуденный зной, растекаясь по пустующим улицам*. "В небольшом поселке кипел жуткий полуденный зной" — образ ёмкости, кастрюли, заполненной кипящим зноем. Поэтому дальнейшее "растекаясь" не сочетается с этим образом: ёмкость уже заполнена. // "Жуткий" — подобные безликие прилагательные не создают картинки. В чём жуткость данного зноя? Я хочу ощутить.

Comment: Да что же это такое, вас надо копировать сразу! Куда текст дели? Но я его успела прочитать.  Класс! Мне нравится все, кроме двух слов: ампутировал и зарулить. Они не вписываются сюда, совершенно чужие. Про жару понятно написано...

Comment: Теперь отвечаю на критику. Моя "кастрюля" переполнена, так что зной перетекает через край – и прямо на улицы.  Вероятно, я стою на центральной площади городка, где особенно жарко (деревьев мало, одни клумбы с цветами). Жуткий? Это надо в словаре посмотреть, чтобы "ощутить": 2. Разг. Чрезвычайный, крайний по силе, степени проявления. Ж. мороз. Ну конечно, слово уже затертое, довольно безликое и малохудожественное. А что, его лучше вообще никогда не использовать?

Comment: @Sharon значит, улицы были вне посёлка, если зной кипел в посёлке, а переливался, чтобы растечься, куда-то ещё? Картинка так и так не складывается.

Comment: Объясняю... Улицы в таких поселках обычно тенистые,  узкие, деревьев много. А на площади только клумбы и памятники разные. Надо так написать: На центральной площади небольшого поселка кипел жуткий полуденный зной, растекаясь по пустующим улицам.

Comment: Текст должен быть таким, чтобы автору не приходилось дополнительно разъяснять читателям, что он имел в виду) *В небольшом поселке кипел жуткий полуденный зной, растекался с площади, открытой вплавленному в зенит солнцу, по тенистым желобам улиц* - как-то так я б написал. Это не очень хорошо, потому что 'растекался' и 'желоб' ассоциируются с влагой, что снижает общее ощущение зноя. Но тем не менее, как вариант...

Comment: Образы у вас интересные, но их слишком много для одного предложения, так что они теряют свою выразительность. Текст должен читаться легко, и во всем должна быть мера. Кстати, мы не учитываем, что это всего лишь  предложение, а контекста вы не видим.  Кстати, растекается не только влага, но и огненная лава из вулкана.

Comment: @Sharon да, можно сократить: *В посёлке кипел полуденный зной, растекался с открытой солнцу площади по затенённым акациями желобам улиц*.

Comment: Да, нормально, но одно слово,  как мне кажется, лишнее (желобы).

Comment: @Sharon да, можно убрать. Главное, чтобы осталась провешенная связующая арочка, в данном случае противопоставление: открытый-затенённый. Это важно. Такие арочки создают связность текста. В моём удалённом примере была арочка: "банный выдох июля" и далее "протопленная атмосфера". Банный-протопленный, образы одного ряда. В моём юмористическом конкурсном ответе и то есть арочка: попробуете отыскать?))

Comment: @Sharon хорошо, тогда я удалю ссылку. Чтобы тут не разводить не по теме, ответьте мне лучше  на почту, хорошо? nektoid@inbox.ru

Comment: ОК, все отправлено